Transformer spams the most frequent character
I noticed that the transformer tends to be optimized to just generate the most frequently appeared character.
For example, I have the following input tokens: ["a", "1", "a", "a", "2", "a", "a", "a", "3"].
And the output should be: ["<sos>", "b", "1", "b", "b", "2", "b", "b", "b", "3", "<eos>"].
After training with the above data, the model just spams the most frequent character like this: ['<sos>', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'].
How can I avoid that kind of issue?
FYI, here is the code I used:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim


seed = 3
device = torch.device("cpu")
torch.manual_seed(seed)
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    device = torch.device("cuda")
    torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)


class OurModel(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, token_to_index):
        """
        Constructor.
        :param token_to_index: We assume index=0 represents the "<sos>" token, and index=1 represents the "<eos>" token.
        """
        super().__init__()
        self.token_to_index = token_to_index
        self.index_to_token = {index: token for token, index in token_to_index.items()}
        self.vocab_size = len(token_to_index)
        # FYI, 512 is the default for the transformer.
        token_vec_dim = 64
        self.embeds = nn.Embedding(self.vocab_size, token_vec_dim)
        self.transformer = nn.Transformer(
            d_model=token_vec_dim,
            # `d_model` must be divisible by `nhead`.
            # FYI, default `nhead` is 8.
            # Also, you will get warnings if you set `nhead` to an odd number.
            nhead=8 if token_vec_dim % 8 == 0 else 2,
            batch_first=True
        )
        self.fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(token_vec_dim, 30),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(30, self.vocab_size)
        )

    def forward(self, sequence, max_iteration=10):
        """
        Generate a sequence of tokens in an autoregressive way.
        The generation ends when the "<eos>" token is generated or reaches the maximum iteration.
        Here is how it works:
        First, we convert tokens into vectors.
        Second, we need two parameters to use `nn.Transformer(src, tgt)`.
        The `src` represents the input vectors.
        Ex: A tensor (of vectors) for ["roses", "are"].
        The `tgt` represents the generated vectors so far.
        Initially, we use the tensor for ["<sos>"].
        The output of `nn.Transformer(src, tgt)` is a tensor with the same shape as the `tgt`.
        For example, if `tgt` was a tensor for ["<sos>"], the output will be a tensor of vectors like [[1, 2]].
        We grab the [1, 2], put it into the fully connected layer to predict the next token.
        Once we got the next token, we append it to the `tgt`.
        For example, the `tgt` for the next iteration could be a tensor for ["<sos>", "red"].
        The transformer's output may look like a tensor of vectors like [[1, 2], [3, 4]].
        Note that we only grab the last element [3, 4] and ignore the rest.
        We put the last element into the fully connected layer to predict the next token.
        If the predicted token is "<eos>", we stop the generation.
        :param sequence: List of tokens. Ex: ["roses", "are"].
        :param max_iteration: We stop generating tokens if it reaches the max_interation without getting the "<eos>" token.
        :return: List of tokens. Ex: ["<sos>", "red", "<eos>"].
        """
        token_indexes_raw = [self.token_to_index[token] for token in sequence]
        # Shape: (token_amount).
        token_indexes_tensor = torch.LongTensor([index for index in token_indexes_raw]).to(device)
        # Shape: (token_amount, token_vec_dim).
        token_vectors = self.embeds(token_indexes_tensor)
        # Shape: (1, token_vec_dim).
        sos_token_vec = self.embeds(torch.LongTensor([0]).to(device))
        # Shape: (generated_token_amount_so_far, token_vec_dim).
        current_target = sos_token_vec
        generated_token_indexes = [0]
        iteration = 1
        predicted_token_index = -1
        while predicted_token_index != 1 and iteration < max_iteration:
            # The shape is the same as the target.
            transformer_output = self.transformer(token_vectors, current_target)
            # Shape: (token_vec_dim).
            last_element = transformer_output[-1]
            # Shape: (vocab_size)
            raw_scores = self.fc(last_element)
            predicted_token_index = torch.argmax(raw_scores).item()
            generated_token_indexes.append(predicted_token_index)
            # Shape: (1, token_vec_dim).
            last_generated_token_vec = self.embeds(torch.LongTensor([predicted_token_index]).to(device))
            current_target = torch.cat((current_target, last_generated_token_vec), dim=0).to(device)
            iteration += 1
        return [self.index_to_token[index] for index in generated_token_indexes]

    def fit(self, sources, targets):
        """
        Train the model.
        Here is how it works:
        First, we convert tokens into vectors.
        Second, we get the output from `nn.Transformer(sources, targets)`.
        The transformer's output will be a batch of generated tokens.
        Note that the output's shape is the same as the shape of targets.
        Then, we put the transformer's output as an input for the fully connected layer.
        The fully connected layer will give a batch of raw scores.
        With each raw scores, we can determine the predicted next token.
        For the loss, we can compare the predicted next token and the actual next token from the target of the transformer.
        For example, the targets were: [["<sos>", "red"], ["<sos>", "green"]].
        The transformer's output was: [[value_1, value_2], [value_3, value_4]].
        The fully connected layer's output was: [[raw_score_1, raw_score_2], [raw_score_3, raw_score_4]].
        The raw_score_1 should've predicted the token "red".
        The raw_score_2 should've predicted the token "<eos>".
        As you can see, the last score corresponds to the "<eos>" token.
        That's why we excluded the "<eos>" token in targets.
        :param sources: A batch of sources in a plain list. Ex: [["roses", "are"], ["limes", "are"]].
        :param targets: A batch of targets in a plain list. Ex: [["red"], ["green"]].
                        Actually, it's supposed to look like this: [["<sos>", "red"], ["<sos>", "green"]].
                        However, this method will put "<sos>" for you.
                        Note that we exclude "<eos>" token because there is nothing to predict after that token.
        :return: None.
        """
        loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        optimizer = optim.Adam(self.parameters())
        for epoch in range(1000):
            batch_source_indexes = [[self.token_to_index[token] for token in source] for source in sources]
            # Shape: (batch_size, number_of_source_token_indexes, token_vec_dim).
            batch_source_vectors = self.embeds(torch.LongTensor(batch_source_indexes).to(device))
            # Note that we add the index of the "<sos>" token at the beginning for each target token.
            batch_target_indexes = [[0] + [self.token_to_index[token] for token in target] for target in targets]
            # Shape: (batch_size, number_of_target_token_indexes, token_vec_dim).
            batch_target_vectors = self.embeds(torch.LongTensor(batch_target_indexes).to(device))
            # Shape: (batch_size, number_of_target_token_indexes, token_vec_dim).
            transformer_output = self.transformer(batch_source_vectors, batch_target_vectors)
            # Shape: (batch_size, number_of_target_token_indexes, vocab_size).
            batch_raw_scores = self.fc(transformer_output)
            # Note that we add the index of the "<eos>" token at the end for each target token.
            batch_correct_token_indexes = [[self.token_to_index[token] for token in target] + [1] for target in targets]
            loss = 0
            for batch_index in range(len(batch_raw_scores)):
                # Shape: (number_of_target_tokens, vocab_size).
                raw_scores = batch_raw_scores[batch_index]
                # Shape: (number_of_target_tokens).
                correct_token_indexes = torch.LongTensor(batch_correct_token_indexes[batch_index]).to(device)
                loss += loss_function(raw_scores, correct_token_indexes)
            print(f"epoch: {epoch}, loss: {loss}")
            if loss < 0.001:
                break
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            optimizer.zero_grad()

def main():
    token_to_index = {
        # sos stands for start of sequence.
        "<sos>": 0,
        # eos stands for end of sequence.
        "<eos>": 1,
        "a": 2,
        "b": 3,
        "1": 4,
        "2": 5,
        "3": 6
    }

    model = OurModel(token_to_index).to(device)

    train_sources = [
        ["a", "1", "a", "a", "2", "a", "a", "a", "3"],
    ]
    train_targets = [
        ["b", "1", "b", "b", "2", "b", "b", "b", "3"],
    ]
    model.fit(train_sources, train_targets)

    input_tokens = ["a", "a", "2"]
    generated_tokens = model(input_tokens)
    print(f"input_tokens: {input_tokens}, generated_tokens: {generated_tokens}")

main()


I found two major modifications that improved the performance significantly.
Firstly, I changed the training process.
Let's say we want to translate English to Spanish.
Previously, my training process looked like the following (pseudocode):
source = ["one", "two", "three"]
target = ["<sos>", "uno", "dos", "tres", "<eos>"]
output = transformer(source, target)
loss = cross_entropy(output, target)

loss.backward()
optimizer.step()

Now, the process looks like the following (pseudocode):
source = ["one", "two", "three"]
target = ["<sos>"]
output = transformer(source, target)
loss = cross_entropy(output, target)

source = ["one", "two", "three"]
target = ["<sos>", "uno"]
output = transformer(source, target)
loss += cross_entropy(output, target)

source = ["one", "two", "three"]
target = ["<sos>", "uno", "dos"]
output = transformer(source, target)
loss += cross_entropy(output, target)

source = ["one", "two", "three"]
target = ["<sos>", "uno", "dos", "tres"]
output = transformer(source, target)
loss += cross_entropy(output, target)

source = ["one", "two", "three"]
target = ["<sos>", "uno", "dos", "tres", "<eos>"]
output = transformer(source, target)
loss += cross_entropy(output, target)

loss.backward()
optimizer.step()

As we can see, the training process became more thorough.
Secondly, I clipped the norm of the gradients like this:
loss.backward()
max_norm = 0.001
torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), max_norm)
optimizer.step()

This reduced the fluctuation of loss values during training.
Additionally, I diversified the dataset and played around with hyperparameters.
Regarding hyperparameter tuning, I realized that higher token vector dimensions or more layers do not necessarily improve performance.
Lastly, here is the modified code:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim


seed = 3
device = torch.device("cpu")
torch.manual_seed(seed)
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    device = torch.device("cuda")
    torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)


class OurModel(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, token_to_index):
        """
        Constructor.
        :param token_to_index: We assume index=0 represents the "<sos>" token, and index=1 represents the "<eos>" token.
        """
        super().__init__()
        self.token_to_index = token_to_index
        self.index_to_token = {index: token for token, index in token_to_index.items()}
        self.vocab_size = len(token_to_index)
        # FYI, 512 is the default for the transformer.
        token_vec_dim = 64
        self.embeds = nn.Embedding(self.vocab_size, token_vec_dim)
        self.transformer = nn.Transformer(
            d_model=token_vec_dim,
            # `d_model` must be divisible by `nhead`.
            # FYI, default `nhead` is 8.
            # Also, you will get warnings if you set `nhead` to an odd number.
            nhead=8 if token_vec_dim % 8 == 0 else 2,
            batch_first=True,
            dropout=0.0,
            num_encoder_layers=1,
            num_decoder_layers=1,
            dim_feedforward=1,
        )
        self.fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(token_vec_dim, 30),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(30, self.vocab_size)
        )

    def forward(self, source_vecs, target_vecs):
        transformer_output = self.transformer(source_vecs, target_vecs)
        last_element = transformer_output[-1]
        return self.fc(last_element)

    def generate(self, sequence, max_iteration=10):
        token_indexes_raw = [self.token_to_index[token] for token in sequence]
        # Shape: (token_amount).
        token_indexes_tensor = torch.LongTensor([index for index in token_indexes_raw]).to(device)
        # Shape: (token_amount, token_vec_dim).
        token_vectors = self.embeds(token_indexes_tensor)
        # Shape: (1, token_vec_dim).
        sos_token_vec = self.embeds(torch.LongTensor([0]).to(device))
        # Shape: (generated_token_amount_so_far, token_vec_dim).
        current_target = sos_token_vec
        generated_token_indexes = [0]
        iteration = 1
        predicted_token_index = -1
        while predicted_token_index != 1 and iteration < max_iteration:
            raw_scores = self.forward(token_vectors, current_target)
            predicted_token_index = torch.argmax(raw_scores).item()
            generated_token_indexes.append(predicted_token_index)
            # Shape: (1, token_vec_dim).
            last_generated_token_vec = self.embeds(torch.LongTensor([predicted_token_index]).to(device))
            current_target = torch.cat((current_target, last_generated_token_vec), dim=0).to(device)
            iteration += 1
        return [self.index_to_token[index] for index in generated_token_indexes]

    def fit(self, sources, targets):
        loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        optimizer = optim.Adam(self.parameters())
        for epoch in range(500):
            total_loss = 0
            for sequence_index in range(len(sources)):
                source_sequence = sources[sequence_index]
                target_sequence = targets[sequence_index]
                source_indexes = [self.token_to_index[token] for token in source_sequence]
                source_vectors = self.embeds(torch.LongTensor(source_indexes).to(device))
                sos_token_vec = self.embeds(torch.LongTensor([0]).to(device))
                current_target = sos_token_vec
                correct_token_indexes = [self.token_to_index[token] for token in target_sequence]
                correct_token_indexes.append(1)
                for target_index in range(len(correct_token_indexes)):
                    raw_scores = self.forward(source_vectors, current_target).reshape(1, -1)
                    correct_token_index = torch.LongTensor([correct_token_indexes[target_index]]).to(device)
                    loss = loss_function(raw_scores, correct_token_index)
                    total_loss += loss
                    correct_token_vec = self.embeds(correct_token_index)
                    current_target = torch.cat((current_target, correct_token_vec), dim=0).to(device)
            print(f"epoch: {epoch}, total_loss: {total_loss}")
            if total_loss < 3.5:
                break
            total_loss.backward()
            torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(self.parameters(), 0.001)
            optimizer.step()
            optimizer.zero_grad()

def main():
    token_to_index = {
        # sos stands for start of sequence.
        "<sos>": 0,
        # eos stands for end of sequence.
        "<eos>": 1,
        "a": 2,
        "b": 3,
        "1": 4,
        "2": 5,
        "3": 6
    }

    model = OurModel(token_to_index).to(device)

    train_sources = [
        ["a"],
        ["1"],
        ["2"],
        ["3"],
        ["a", "1"],
        ["a", "a"],
        ["a", "a", "2"],
        ["a", "a", "a"],
        ["a", "a", "a", "3"],
        ["a", "1", "a", "a", "2", "a", "a", "a", "3"],
    ]
    train_targets = [
        ["b"],
        ["1"],
        ["2"],
        ["3"],
        ["b", "1"],
        ["b", "b"],
        ["b", "b", "2"],
        ["b", "b", "b"],
        ["b", "b", "b", "3"],
        ["b", "1", "b", "b", "2", "b", "b", "b", "3"],
    ]
    model.fit(train_sources, train_targets)

    input_tokens = ["a", "a", "2"]
    generated_tokens = model.generate(input_tokens)
    print(f"input_tokens: {input_tokens}, generated_tokens: {generated_tokens}")

main()

